# JPDA modification listener, some kind of JVMHotRedeployListener

Tags: java, listener, jpda

I am hot-deploying code of methods in my development-environment.

The code is affected immediately unless the code change the signature of methods or the structure of the class.

**This works fine, I have no problem with that.**

Unfortunately I must trigger the execution of the method again in order to have this code executed. Can I register a Listener that get notified when the JVM recieves a JPDA-HotCodeReplace?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever IDE/debugger you use, Hot Code Replace eventually ends up in calling either [RedefineClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RedefineClasses) or [RetransformClasses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#RetransformClasses) JVM TI function.

So, the idea is to intercept these two functions and call listeners upon their invocation. This can be achieved with a native (JNI) library.

**HotCodeReplaceListener.c**

```
#include <jvmti.h>

typedef struct {
    void* unused1[86];
    jvmtiError (JNICALL *RedefineClasses)(jvmtiEnv*, jint, const jvmtiClassDefinition*);
    void* unused2[64];
    jvmtiError (JNICALL *RetransformClasses)(jvmtiEnv*, jint, const jclass*);
} JVMTIFunctions;

jvmtiError (JNICALL *orig_RedefineClasses)(jvmtiEnv*, jint, const jvmtiClassDefinition*);
jvmtiError (JNICALL *orig_RetransformClasses)(jvmtiEnv*, jint, const jclass* classes);

static JavaVM* _vm;

// Call back to static HotCodeReplace.fireListeners() method
static void fire_listeners() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    (*_vm)->GetEnv(_vm, (void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);

    jclass hot_code_replace = (*env)->FindClass(env, "HotCodeReplace");
    if (hot_code_replace != NULL) {
        jmethodID file_listeners = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, hot_code_replace, "fireListeners", "()V");
        if (file_listeners != NULL) {
            (*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, hot_code_replace, file_listeners);
        }
    }
}

jvmtiError RedefineClassesHook(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, jint class_count, const jvmtiClassDefinition* class_definitions) {
    jvmtiError result = orig_RedefineClasses(jvmti, class_count, class_definitions);
    fire_listeners();
    return result;
}

jvmtiError RetransformClassesHook(jvmtiEnv* jvmti, jint class_count, const jclass* classes) {
    jvmtiError result = orig_RetransformClasses(jvmti, class_count, classes);
    fire_listeners();
    return result;
}

// This function is automatically called when JNI library is loaded
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    void* jvmti;
    (*vm)->GetEnv(vm, &jvmti, JVMTI_VERSION_1_0);
    _vm = vm;

    // Change pointers to JVM TI functions, saving their original addresses
    JVMTIFunctions* functions = *(JVMTIFunctions**)jvmti;
    orig_RedefineClasses = functions->RedefineClasses;
    orig_RetransformClasses = functions->RetransformClasses;
    functions->RedefineClasses = RedefineClassesHook;
    functions->RetransformClasses = RetransformClassesHook;

    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Now in Java code we just need to load this JNI library. `fireListeners` method will be called from the native code using JNI.

**HotCodeReplace.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

public class HotCodeReplace {
    private static final List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    public static void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private static void fireListeners() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onReplace();
        }
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void onReplace();
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("HotCodeReplaceListener");
    }
}
```

**How to use**

```
HotCodeReplace.addListener(() -> System.out.println("Classes changed!"));
```

### Update

There is no pure Java API to get notifications for class redifinition, except for [`jdk.ClassRedefinition`](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8238236) JFR event appeared in JDK 15:

```
var rs = new RecordingStream();
rs.enable("jdk.ClassRedefinition");
rs.onEvent("jdk.ClassRedefinition", event -> {
    System.out.println("Classes changed!");
});
rs.startAsync();
```

The closest JDK 8 alternative is to attach a Java agent that registers dummy [ClassFileTransformer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) to receive callbacks for every loaded or redefined class. The downside of this approach is that the callback fires for every single class, but *before* the actual redefinition. However, if immediate synchronous notification is not required, you can workaround it with a background timer.

```
import java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer;
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HotCodeReplace {
    private static final List<Listener> listeners = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
    private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);

    public static void addListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void removeListener(Listener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private static void fireListeners() {
        for (Listener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onReplace();
        }
    }

    public interface Listener {
        void onReplace();
    }

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                                    ProtectionDomain pd, byte[] classFile) {
                if (classBeingRedefined != null) {
                    executor.getQueue().clear();
                    executor.schedule(HotCodeReplace::fireListeners, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }, true);
    }
}
```

Note: in order to use Instrumentation API, you'll have to start the JVM with `-javaagent` option or use Dynamic Attach to attach an agent in runtime.

Comment: A JNI-solution hm? I have to spend the bounty within 17 hours. Hard to check what you coded within 17 hours from now. Even ignoring the lack of threadsafety ... See I expected to have a solution that uses the JDW-Protocol (JDWP). Indeed this may disqualify the `dt_shmem` transportation but it does not need a low-level workaround.

Comment: @Grim Why do you think the solution is not thread safe? Note [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).

Comment: JDWP is an communication protocol between the debugger and the JVM. Are you implementing your own debugger? JDWP agent works on top of JVM TI. This solution utilizes JVM TI directly without need to specify additional agent on JVM startup.

Comment: @Grim Anyway, I've updated the answer with Java-level alternatives. BTW, I don't really care about bounty, I just like interesting JVM related questions :)

Comment: Ah, I did not know about COWAL. Its threadsafe, sorry my fault. Also my reservations about bounty was wrong, sorry. Java15 is late but a 100% valid answer, also I have no doublt in upgrade to JDK15. 1 Second interval is ok, I guess. I check the answer and mark this as correct answer soon. Thank you